# Why can't I write to a mounted USB hard disk drive?

Tags: hard-drive, mount, fstab

I am trying to mount a USB HDD. A create a folder here:

```
/media/pi/HDD
```

My HDD is formated to `ext2`

After that, I modified my `/etc/fstab` and add this line:

```
/dev/sda1       /media/pi/HDD   ext2    rw,defaults,user     0       0
```

Then reboot, and I can see, the mounted HDD, but the owner and the group is `root`.

Thus, any app can't write this folder. For example, Chromium cannot download anything to this folder, and I also can't use transmission to download in this folder neither.

If i check the `/media` folder belongs to `pi:pi`

My question is, how can I mount this HDD as `pi` user on boot?

Comment: Please run `lsblk --fs` from the command line, and include the output of that command in your question.

Comment: Check permissions on `/media/pi/HDD` (where you presumably want to write), not on `/media`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have `user` in the options of your `fstab`, I'd suggest you try to run `sudo chown -R pi:pi /media/pi/HDD` once it is mounted. This applies the owner recursively to all files and directories of the drive.

I'm not sure if this is appropriate if you have some user rights management going on on the drive though.

Answer (score 0):

When you have unplugged the HDD, run chown pi:pi on the actual mount pount not just the parent folder, so in your case /media/pi/HDD.

In Linux a subfolder or a file can have totally different file access flags than its parent folder.

Comment: hello, if i unplug the HDD and run sudo chown pi:pi /media/pi/HDD nothing happens. And afther check who is the owner of the folder i can see it's pi. But if i replug the hdd the system mount it to media but with this name: 2c9227b9-1f54-4971-bae2-f8bfaa16ae8b at this state i can write.. Then i restart and fstab mount the device again o /media/pi/HDD and this 2c9227b9-1f54-4971-bae2-f8bfaa16ae8b drive not shown anymore and canno write he mounted folder again.. :( what shold i do ?

Comment: Are you sure, your device name is sda1? To check this, plug in your HDD and run df -h

Answer (score 0):

Better than use 'sda1' is to know the *UUID* with this command:

```
sudo blkid /dev/sda1
```

Using this number go and edit 'fstab' file:

```
UUID=whathever_you_obtain_from_blkid /media/pi/HDD  ext2  defaults,user  0  0
```

And give permission to everybody (777) to try, after that you can search to fine tune permission to HDD folder:

```
sudo chmod 777 /media/pi/HDD
```